# Prove $T$ is a linear transformation and find $\ker T$ and $\mathrm{im} T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P_n$ be the vector space of all real polynomials of degree less than or equal to n.

Let $T : P_3 \rightarrow P_3 $ be defined by $T(p(x)) = xp'(x) - 3p'(x)$, where $p'(x)$ represents the formal derivative of $p(x)$.

I am not sure if I am doing correctly please correct me if I did anything wrong.

Let $T(p_1(x)) = xp_1'(x)-3p_1'(x)$ and $T(p_2(x)) = xp_2'(x)-3p_2'(x)$

since $ xp_1'(x)-3p_1'(x) + xp_2'(x)-3p_2'(x) = (xp_1'(x) + xp_2'(x)) + (-3p_1'(x) -3p_2'(x)) = x(p_1'(x) +p_2'(x)) -3(p_1'(x) + p_2'(x))$

so that $T(p_1(x) +p_2(x)) = T(p_1(x)) + T(p_2(x)).$

and $T(λp(x)) =  λxp'(x) - λ3p'(x) =λ(xp'(x) - 3p'(x))$

Now I can say T is a linear transformaion.

Any hint on how to find kerT and imT?

Comment: What's $P_3$ again?

Comment: No, that's definitely wrong. $x_1$ doesn't mean anything in the vector space of polynomials. You want $T(p_1(x))$ and $T(q_1(x))$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Previous question was letting $P_n$ be the vector space of all real polynomials of degree less than or equal to n.

Comment: @user164945 Mention the context, please. Nobody will go checking through your question list in order to decipher your question in order to help you.

Comment: For the kernel, what polynomials of degree $\le 3$ have the property that $(x-3)p'(x)$ is the zero polynomial? For the image, certainly all the functions in the image are divisible by $x-3$. Is every polynomial of degree $\le 3$ which is divisible by $x-3$ in the image?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am right this time?

Comment: You haven't clearly show $T(p_1+p_2)=T(p_1)+T(p_2)$. You need that $(p_1+p_2)'=p_1'+p_2'$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How about this time?

Comment: @AndréNicolas so for the kernel, is it when x=3 i.e. sp(3,0,0). I am still not really certain about the image part.

Comment: No, we need $p'(x)=0$, so $p(x)$ a constant polynomial.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why do we need to show that? If I remember correctly, You only need to prove addition and multiplication to show it is linear transformation

Comment: The comment is not about the linear transformation part, it is about identifying the kernel and image.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry, That was my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $T$ is composited by two linear transformation.

$T_1:P_2\rightarrow P_3$ which satisfies
$$T_1(p(x))=(x-3)p(x)$$

$T_2:P_3\rightarrow P_2$ which satisfies 
$$T_2(p(x))=p'(x)$$

We have $T=T_1\circ T_2$.

---

Because $T_1$ is injection and $T_2$ is surjection, then we get 
$$\text{Ker}(T)=\{p(x)\in P_3:p'(x)=0\}=\mathbb R$$ 
and 
$$\text{Im}(T)=\{(x-3)p(x)\in P_3:p(x)\in P_2\}=\{p(x)\in P_3:x-3|p(x)\}$$

Comment: Are you saying that in order to prove T is linear transformation, I need to prove both $T_1$ and $T_2$ to be linear transformation so that T is linear transformation?

Comment: Not necessarily. Your direct proof is very efficient.

Comment: So the way you were doing is more about how to solve $Ker(T)$ and $Im(T)$ right?

Comment: Yes, I think the answer is more relative to the properties of two maps I mention.